# Protect react component with simple hard-coded password

Tags: reactjs, components, password-protection

I have few components in my app, one of them is admin component (or admin page with data). What is the most simple way for protecting that component with password. I want to require password when you click on component, and if passwords match, just render the component. (I don't need authentication services, just hard-coded password).

Comment: You can use component did mount method inside that method you can render simple text field with hard coded pw If user entered pw correctly u can render others but this is not much secure way

Answer (score 0):

Found best way to do this, it is creating modal with portal and render it in desired component